# (Умный) Липкий Navbar "Sticky"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Реализовал липкий navbar при помощи jQuery, работает как нужно, но после оказалось, что этот navbar должен быть на некоторых страницах вместо header (а в скрипте реализовано прилипание и отлипание при определенной высоте пикселей).
Кто может помочь так сказать с умным липким navbar, что бы он прилипал в точке где расположен, автоматически, а не в конкретно заданной высоте?
Вроде бы нашел подходящее решение но оно отказывается нормально работать, постоянно navbar к самому верху подымает (https://codepen.io/aklima/pen/oeyjLd)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
var num = 200; //number of pixels before modifying styles

$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
        $('.menu').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $('.menu').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
});
```

```css
.fixed {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
}

.menu {
    color:#FFF;
    height:2em;
    padding:.5em;
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="menu">
<div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
          </div>
          <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li class="active"><a href="./">Default</a></li>
              <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
              <li><a href="../navbar-fixed-top/">Fixed top</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
      </div>
</div>
<div style="width:300px; margin-top:270px">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.</div>
```

Comment: С помощью css свойства `sticky`?

Comment: Да, был вариант, но встал вопрос о кросбраузерности